# Copy EVERYTHING from windows machine to remote unix machine

Tags: unix, copy

I'm trying to copy everything over from a windows machine to a linux machine using the command line. I want literally every single file from the machine. Is there any way I can achieve this using the command line?

I guess you can technically say I want to "make a backup"

Thanks,
-JC

Comment: What do you mean by "remote"? Can you mount the Windows hard drive / partition? Is it only accessible over the network? Do you have SSH set up on the remote machine? More details are better.

Comment: You can try [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)

Comment: Trying to copy files from an win box on my internal network to my centos VPS

Comment: You may find that you won't be able to copy every file on the Windows box because they may be locked; or you may be able to copy it, but its internal representation isn't consistent. For instance, the registry files for your user may not have been flushed to disk, and so you copy off a file that is old or only has a couple updates. Aside from that, I'd recommend running something like bacula, which is a full backup solution that can run between Linux and Windows.